# I cannot succeed in using the fluxbox ResizeTo function

Tags: fluxbox

I often use a stack of terminals one above the other. And I've notice I do it always the same way, resizing each terminal window so as it occupies circa 1/3rd of the screen. I wanted to have a short key for doing this automatically.

Obviously the command exists ([cf. fluxbox manual](http://fluxbox.org/help/man-fluxbox-keys.php)), called ResizeTo.

in `~/.fluxbox/keys` I have tried:

- `Shift Mod4 a :ResizeTo -100% -33%`
- `Shift Mod4 a :ResizeTo 100% 33%`

I've also launched `Reconfigure` so as to have the new keymapping working.
However when pressing `Shift + Windows key + a`, there is nothing happening.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Doesn't a restart of Fluxbox help?

Comment: No, it doesn't help. Log out/in neither. I suppose it's my syntax.

Comment: Check out `wmctrl` and `xdotool` - there is a lot on that [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61037/how-to-resize-application-windows-in-an-arbitrary-direction-not-vertical-and-no), although the question itself is a somewhat different scenario (actually, my answer to that question, would be better as an answer to _your_ question).

Comment: state, which version of `fluxbox` you are using.

Comment: @akira `fluxbox --version` returns 1.3.2

Comment: http://git.fluxbox.org/fluxbox.git/tree/ChangeLog#n79, version 1.3.3.

Comment: @akira I use the ubuntu depot which offers me the package for version 1.3.2 Do you think it's safe that I use the 1.3.3 version ? I admit I am not tempted, Fluxbox is now my main and almost unique window manager, and I don't feel like experimenting. I didn't uninstall unity only because of the nice really graphical login page.

Comment: @StephaneRolland: a) the display manager (login screen) is separated from the window manager. b) the ubuntu / debian maintainer of the fluxbox package is _very_ close to the developers of fluxbox (me). there are backports, there are even some nightly .deb packages based upon nightly builds iirc. and yeah, usually it's pretty safe for you to use the latest version (soonish to become 1.3.4).

Comment: @akira when I wrote `apt-get remove unity` the unity-login-screen-management package was on the list of all the packages to be removed. So I just kept unity. I didn't dig in the dependencies to try to understand. as for b)... well... thanx for telling me it... gonna think about 1.3.3. maybe one day I'll be courageous :-)

Comment: https://launchpad.net/unity-greeter .. the login-thingy is basically a "theme" to lightdm. so, just remove unity, take the dependencies with it, reinstall either unity-greeter or just lightdm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it does not accept % even though it's documented like that.

If you don't use multiple resolutions try giving it the pixel size without %.

Comment: good ! I have several screens, so I have multiple resolutions. However one of the screens is my main screen, where I always put my stack of terminals into. And for the moment your trick simply does it very well:-).